# Lenovo X220 reboots instead of shutting down

Tags: shutdown, reboot

When I push the shutdown button in the shutdown dialog my notebook (Lenovo X220) does a restart instead.

I also tried running the "sudo shutdown -P now" from command line -> same result!

Before upgrading to 11.10 everything was fine.

Anybody else experiences this malfunction? Any tips to make it work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm here on Xubuntu 11.10 with an x220 i5 and experienced the same issue.

Installing laptop-mode-tools (with `aptitude install laptop-mode-tools --without-recommends`) fixed it for me.

(found the hint via https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi/+question/168617)

I came up with another solution that does not involve laptop-mode-tools. *Maybe* it works for others.
The problem *seems* to occur when power-management for PCI(e) devices is enabled (set to "auto").
Here are two ways to check that:

1. run `powertop`, switch to the "Tunables" tab and see if your "Runtime PM for PCI*" entries are marked as "Good"
2. `cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/power/control` and see if it outputs some "auto" values.
   "auto" causes the shutdown problems on my machine while "on" does not.

I created an init.d script to handle that (and other stuff like setting battery charge threshs and the like), available via [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8w2eMXYZ).

**Note:**

- The script runs fine on my machine. This does not mean it will run on others due to missing programs, etc.
- The script does more than (potentially) circumventing the shutdown problem, so please read it first.
- I am not sure that "auto" brings any benefit at all ;)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I executed the recommended command. It said that laptop-mode-tools is already installed but somehow now it works! Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I have laptop-mode-tools installed but the problem occurs anyway. Oneiric with gnome/unity, on an i7 x220. Happens whether I do `sudo shutdown -h now` or shutdown via the gui. My only workaround is to hold the power button after reboot.