# x220 shutdown turns into reboot

Tags: 13.04, power-management, shutdown, suspend, hibernate

So first off,

I did try this, and many more:

**[Lenovo X220 reboots instead of shutting down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69420/lenovo-x220-reboots-instead-of-shutting-down)**
powertop->Tunables->Runtime PM for PCI*" entries are all marked as "**Bad**"

```
cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/power/control<br/>
```

All are set to **Auto**
Laptop Tools/mode do not help.
inserting the script running the script results in

```
./thinkpower: 42: ./thinkpower: cannot create /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT*/stop_charge_thresh: Directory nonexistent
```

There is a multitude of  install Laptop-Tools, which again, are not of much use it seems

Shutdown -> Full rebooot
Hibernate && Suspend brings me to login screen

the only way I can stop my Laptop right now is by holding my powerbutton

```
ThinkPad-X220 3.8.0-30-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 20:52:24 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring
```

Comment: Try this command once: `sudo shutdown -f now`. Do you you get the same problem?

Comment: This does bring me to a commandline screen where it hangs saying system WILL SHUTDOWN FOR MAINTENANCE, but never does. Hangs there, still need to hold the powerbutton for full shutdown.

Comment: do you get a login window when your system boots?

Answer (score 0):

**Try these**

I am not sure that it would work for you, since the steps are very long and I would not be able to suggest you as comments for very long step, so I'm writing it as an answer.

- Open Terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute this command:

  ```
  $ sudo pkill -u vevmesteren
  ```

  if `vevmesteren` is your Ubuntu user name.
- Then in the login screen chose different shell like `Gnome Classic(No effects)`, you may get `Ubuntu`, `Ubuntu 2D`, `Gnome Classic`, `Gnome Classic(No effects)`
- Then login again using (be sure that `Gnome Classic(No effects)` has been selected).
- Try to shutdown your system. If fails then execute following command to restart:

  ```
  $ sudo reboot now
  ```

Try it once. It will not Change harm anything, or change something in your system. Reply what happens.

Comment: Same result shutdown results in reboot, Reboot in hangup at System will reboot for maintenance...

Comment: hmm.. It is going to be tough for you..

Comment: I am good with tough,as long as there is a way ;)

Comment: there are some messages that are displayed in shell, when I shut down, but, given that the shut down happens so fast, I have to time to read them, how would I go about reading them. In varnish I -configtest, is there something similar on shutdown? I will try a |less but not sure if that will work. More to follow

Comment: yeah, as expected, a less did not do it, shutdown -P now results in yet another reboot.

Comment: Those messages are not that much important. They just shows that some processes are going to be stopped. To get those message you can try this: `sudo shutdown -f now > message`. Later you can open message using any text editor to see the contents..

Comment: message file is empty, syslog contains nothing of note, well at least not if I do not know what I am looking for. WARNINGs yes, no apparent fails...

Comment: UPDATE : Tried resetting my system like so: sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a. That did not work, went ahead and did a reinstall with the CD, still a no go. So now I am wondering if this might be Kernel related. I have read similar issues where the Kernel is blamed for an issue like this one. Will try and boot into a previous Kernel and report back...

Comment: Nope, that did not work...

Comment: Ok run these commands : `sudo uname -a` and `sudo lsb_release -a` . Edit your quetion and paste the result of these commands.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I did add the results of uname and lsb_release to the questions let's see if I get some new nibbles

Comment: Still Stuck! Anyone?

Comment: I am starting to have a feeling that it is the Thinkad itself, andthat it has nothing to do with Ubuntu...update shortly